# How to install minitab on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, software-recommendation

I want to install minitab on my machine, running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

How can I install it, or something similar?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** minitab is a commercial package running on Windows only.  Have you tried contacting the software publisher?

Comment: Hey Fabby! Thanx for the quick revert. Could you pls suggest any free alternative software for Ubuntu.

Comment: Karel already beat me to that. (don't forget to accept his answer if it did help you)

Comment: 1) Alternatives are listed at https://alternativeto.net/software/minitab/?platform=linux 2) Software recommendations are best discussed in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ 3) Iinstalling MiniTab with WINE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495460/time-to-install-minitab-using-wine https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=213 or CodeWeaver https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/crossover/minitab-17 appears problematic. 4) If your PC hardware supports Virtualization, see https://data.library.virginia.edu/files/minitab17.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](/q/988/175814)

Comment: Installing third party software on Ubuntu is 100% on topic. Hard to think of a justification for making it off topic. Answers to such questions are very likely to help future visitors. "You can't but try this instead" type answers are valid.

Answer (score 4):

R is a system for statistical computation and graphics. It consists of a language plus a runtime environment with graphics, a debugger, access to certain system functions, and the ability to run programs stored in script files.

The core of R is an interpreted computer language which allows branching and looping as well as modular programming using functions. Additionally, several thousand extension "packages" are available from CRAN, the Comprehensive R Archive Network, many also as Debian packages, named *r-cran-<name>*. For R an extension (library) [R Commander](https://www.rcommander.com/) exists, which brings a GUI to perform most things that Minitab is capable of.

To install R and RStudio in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install r-base libopenblas-base libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libjpeg62       
cd ~/Downloads  
wget -c --tries=3 --timeout=120 https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-xenial-1.1.419-amd64.deb  
sudo apt install ./rstudio-xenial-1.1.379-amd64.deb
```

Comment: Uitslover!  **;-)  +1**

Comment: Hey Karel, thanx a ton for the answer. I already have R installed, but, a course I am enrolled in demands to use minitab. So, could u suggest any workaround to install minitab on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS & use it for free...

Comment: Fill out the form at the Minitab website and they will send you an email with a link to download your free 30-day Minitab trial. That's as good as it gets. People pay more money for blue jeans with holes in them than for regular jeans. They could save money by buying regular jeans and making holes in the jeans themselves.